# c# If Control in single row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am using asp.net mvc view , in order to use if control .

**My Code:**

```
<div class="panel-body @(((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LastStatus == "" ? "collapse" : string.Empty)">
```

**My Question about above if control:**

I want to check

```
If ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LastStatus == null ||
If ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LastStatus == ""
```

I want to use `? "collapse" : else : string.Empty)">`

How can i use If not null and If not "" in one row in my code?

Comment: Use String.IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: Any help please thanks.How can i use not null and not "" else in one row if code ?

Comment: may you please share code example , if works i will accept best answer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're checking whether a string value is either `null` or `""` then just use `IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LastStatus) ? "collapse" : string.Empty
```

If you want to combine multiple conditions in a conditional expression, you can do so with logical operators.  For example:

```
if (someCondition && someOtherCondition)
```

This would require that both conditions be true.  (If you use the `||` operator instead then it would require that *at least one* condition be true.)

So in a `?:` operator that might look something like:

```
(someCondition || someOtherCondition) ? someValue : someOtherValue
```

Logical segments of conditional expressions can be grouped with parentheses, so you can include as many as you like:

```
(condition1 || (condition2 && condition3)) ? someValue : someOtherValue
```

Technically you can construct conditions and other expressions as large as you'd like, though of course code readability and maintainability becomes an issue pretty quickly.  Extracting the logic into separate methods helps keep the code more organized.

Comment: i will try it now , is it possible to use if not null and if not "" else in one row if ?

Comment: @user3722851: Of course.  You can put as many conditions as you like in any conditional expression.  Just combine them with logical operators such as `&&` for "and" or `||` for "or".

Comment: may you please also send it's code example according to my code thanks